# How to use UIImageView load() fuction with the completionHandler in swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, completionhandler

I'm loading an image using a url but want to display a loading icon while the image is being loaded. I found this method signature that has a completionHandler that I want to use but don't know exactly how to use the completionHandler.

UIImageView.load( URL: URLLiteralConvertible, placeholder: UIImage?, completionHandler (NSURL, UIImage?, NSError?, CacheType) -> ())

Does anyone know how to call this? Thanks!

**What I have so far**

```
let imgUrl = NSURL(string: imgURL)

self.img.load(imgUrl!, placeholder: UIImage(named: "greySq.png"), completionHandler: { _ in

} //Throws a syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't need to call the load function with the completion handler to get what I wanted. Using the variation below gave me my desired result.

```
self.img.load(imgUrl!, placeholder: UIImage(named: "greySq.png")){ _ in                
    self.formView.spinner.stopAnimating() 
}
```